# Subtrair um dia em todas as datas dentro de 5 meses

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando subtrair um dia de todos os dados do banco no período de 5 meses e atualizar o banco com esses novos valores. A consulta abaixo retorna os dados já descontado um dia:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DateAndTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM floattablediario 
  WHERE DateAndTime between '2020-01-01' AND '2020-05-26'
  AND TagIndex = 0
order by DateAndTime asc;
```

Se eu fizer um update com base nessa consulta, ele não atualiza todos os dados:

```
UPDATE floattablediario SET DateAndTime = DATE_SUB(DateAndTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  WHERE DateAndTime between '2020-01-01' AND '2020-05-26'
  AND TagIndex = 0
order by DateAndTime asc;
```

Como eu poderia fazer esse update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE A FUNÇÃO DATE(expr)

```
 UPDATE floattablediario SET DateAndTime = DATE_SUB(DateAndTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  WHERE DATE(DateAndTime) between '2020/01/01' AND '2020/05/26'
    AND TagIndex = 0
```